# Ayuda con Routes en Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

He estado trabajando en una aplicación web a través de *Laravel* en *Windows* (usando *Laragon*). Soy nuevo en el uso de este framework y he encontrado un inconveniente:

Cuando utilizo los *Routes* como por ejemplo:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');
```

Va todo bien sin embargo, si hago lo siguiente:

```
Route::get('casos/{nombre?}', 'PagesController@caso');
```

Al actualizar la web en el navegador, noto que todas mis URI de mis *scripts*, *css*  e incluso imágenes que uso en la vista de la web, cambian, anteponiéndose una carpeta que recibe por nombre: `casos/`.

Del mismo modo ocurre al hacerlo de esta forma:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middlewere'=> 'auth'],function(){
     Route::get('donantes','Administrador\CasosController@home');
});
```

Si lo creo una ruta de esa forma, en la web, a todos mis enlaces de los *css*, *js*, imágenes, etc. se le antepone, en este caso, el prefijo `admin/`.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: podrias mostrar como estas declarando los escripts, css o las imagenes en las vistas ?

Comment: Sí, lo hago de la siguiente manera: `<script src="libs/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que html reconoce las rutas de tus archivos de manera relativa, por lo que buscará esos archivos justo en la url indicada por tu ruta.

Suponiendo que intentas llamar a un archivo `script.js`:

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Entonces si por ejemplo estás en `admin/index` se asumirá que tu *script* está ubicado así:

```
/admin
    /index.html
    /js
        /script.js
```

Pero si ahora tu url cambia a admin/donantes/index, se asumirá que tu *script* está en otro directorio:

```
/admin
    /donantes
        /index.html
        /js
            /script.js
```

A esto se llama **[rutas relativas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)**, pero lo que necesitas es tener *rutas absolutas* pra acceder a los recursos de tus archivos.

Sin embargo Laravel como otros frameworks tienen implementadas funciones ***[helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#urls)*** para dar solución a ésto, en este caso para *urls* se tiene principalmente éstos:

**asset**

> Que genera una URL para un recurso usando el esquema actual de la solicitud (HTTP o HTTPS):

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>
```

**route**

> Que genera una URL para el nombre de una ruta:

```
<a href="{{ route('nombre_de_ruta') }}">Link</a>
```

**url**

> Que genera una URL completamente calificada para una ruta dada:

```
<a href="{{ url('/admin/donantes') }}">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el problema puede ser probablemente que estes cargando los archivos con rutas relativas. como por ejemplo:

```
<script src="js/archivo.js"></script>
```

En Laravel existe una funcion en php que puedes utilizar para indicar rutas y de esta forma la ruta se mantiene formateada correctamente. Esta funcion automaticamente le agrega el dominio al principio. [Puedes leer mas de las multiples funciones que existen aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-asset)

Pero un ejemplo puede ser el siguiente:

```
<script src="{{ url('js/archivo.js') }}"></script>
```

o

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/archivo.js') }}"></script>
```

Espero esto te funcione.